How to declare a function to make an array of N integers as argument in MIPS assembly
This code will read integers from the user and store them sequentially in memory starting from the address pointed to by $a0 (the array address). It will read exactly $a1 integers, as specified by the user. Once all integers are read, it returns to the caller.
In here I just declared space of array and simple messages
.data

arr: .space 32    # Reserve space for 8 integers
msg: .asciiz "Enter the number of elements to store: "
msg1: .asciiz "Enter an integer value: "

Here is the main program that are my callers placed
.text

main:
    # Print message
    la $a0, msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Read number of elements
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s2,$v0
    move $a1,$v0   # Store number of elements in $a1

    # Prepare array address
    la $a0, arr

    # Call read_array_function
    jal read_array_function
    
    move $a0,$v0    #move contents of the return value to print array function argument
    move $a1,$s2
    
    jal print_array_function
    
    jal read_array_function
    
   

    # End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

This is the function to read to array
read_array_function:
    sub $sp, $sp, 24  # Allocate space on stack
    sw $a0, 0($sp)    # Save array address to stack
    sw $a1, 4($sp)    # Save number of elements to stack
    sw $ra, 8($sp)    # Save return address to stack
    sw $zero, 12($sp) # Initialize loop counter
    sw $a0, 16($sp) #save start address of the array to stack to return it at the end_read

    lw $t0, 0($sp)    # Load array address from stack
    lw $t1, 4($sp)    # Load number of elements from stack
    lw $t2, 12($sp)   # Load loop counter from stack
    lw $t3, 8($sp)    # Load return address from stack
    lw $t4, 16($sp) #Load start address of the array to stack

read_loop:
    beq $t2, $t1, end_read  # Exit loop if counter >= number of elements
    
    la $a0,msg1
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    
    # Read integer from user
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    # Store user input in array
    sw $v0, ($t0)          # Store user input at array address
    addi $t0, $t0, 4      # Move to next element in array
    addi $t2, $t2, 1      # Increment loop counter
    j read_loop            # Repeat loop

end_read:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)    # Restore return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 24 # Restore stack pointer
    move $v0,$t4
    jr $t3           # Return to caller


This is the function to read to array
    
print_array_function:

    sub $sp,$sp,12      #dedicate 12 bytes from memory stack
    sw  $a0,0($sp)      #save argument address of the array to stack
    sw  $zero,4($sp)    #loop counter = 0
    sw  $a1,8($sp)          #number of elements in array
    
    lw  $t0,0($sp)      #load address of the array to $t0
    lw  $t1,4($sp)      #load loop counter to $t1
    lw  $t2,8($sp)      #number of elements
    
    
print_loop:
    
    beq  $t1,$t2,end_print
    lw $a0,($t0)        #load address of the array element 
    li $v0,1            
    syscall
    addi $t0,$t0,4      # Move to next element in array by adding 4
    addi $t1,$t1,1      # Increment loop counter
    j print_loop
    
end_print:
    addi $sp, $sp, 12   # Restore stack pointer
    jr $ra              # Return to caller

I tried to declare array of 8 integers and made it but N integers is a bit tricky I think

So, are you basically asking how to allocate an array dynamically? Use the appropriate syscall. In mars/spim that would be #9 with the number of bytes in $a0.

uhh silly me there was a syscall for that I dont know thanks for reply Jester !
